# Creating a mssql database backup using odbc on mac

Tags: macos, sql-server-2008, t-sql, automation, database-backups

So, MSSQL is nice enough to have given us a nifty little sql code for creating a database backup from a command line:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [db_name] TO  DISK = N'D:\backups\back.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'db_name', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

However, I am looking to be able to run this command from a php or even shell script on a remote Mac server.

The Problem I am running into is when I try to change the DISK to say my admin home directory, it keeps complaining to me about:

```
Cannot open backup device 'D:\PATH\ON\SERVER\/Users/admin/back.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
```

Anyone know what I am missing here? I would be very appreciative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server's `BACKUP` command does a backup to the *database server's local disk*. That means that setting the path to a directory on the client machine makes no sense.

If you want a database backup stored on your client machine, I can basically see 3 options;

- Back up to a temporary location accessible from the database server, and copy it from there to your client.
- Mount a disk shared from your client machine on your database server as for example `X:\` and do the backup to that disk.
- Find another backup solution that does backups in a different way (sorry, no, I have no recommendations)

Comment: Aw Man... All my hopes and dreams crushed... Thats okay. I found a way around this per your suggestion thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use RasorSQL, it's a client for mac and windows.
https://razorsql.com/